# How can I get HttpServletRequest when in an HttpSessionListener?

Tags: java, session, jsf, jakarta-ee, request

How can I access request headers from a SessionListener?

I need to set a timeout on the current session when it is created. The timeout needs to vary based on a header in the HttpServletRequest. I already have a SessionListener (implements HttpSessionListener) that logs the creation and destruction of new sessions, and it seems to be the most logical place to set the timeout.

I've tried the following, but it always sets ctx to null.

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `HttpSessionListener` does not have access to the request because it is invoked when no request has been made—to notify of session destruction.

So, a `Filter` or `Servlet` would be better places to examine the request and specify the session timeout.

Answer (score 2):

```
FacesContext ctx = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
```

JSF contexts are per-request and thread-local. So, this method call will probably return null outside the JSF controller invocations (e.g. [FacesServlet.service](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/webapp/FacesServlet.html#service(javax.servlet.ServletRequest,%20javax.servlet.ServletResponse))) - so, other threads and any requests that don't pass through the Faces servlet mapping.

It is technically possible to set this time-out using a JSF mechanism - you could use a [phase listener](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseListener.html) to check for a session after [RENDER RESPONSE](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/event/PhaseId.html), though you would still have to [cast to the servlet API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getSession(boolean)) to set the time-out. The advantage of phase listeners is that they can be registered either globally in faces-config ([see spec](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/reference/api/index.html)) or [for specific views](http://java.sun.com/javaee/javaserverfaces/1.2_MR1/docs/tlddocs/f/phaseListener.html). A global phase listener defined in a JAR with a *META-INF/faces-config.xml* can be dropped into multiple WARs, allowing you to easily reuse the functionality.

(You could also [override how the session is provisioned to JSF](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContextFactory.html), but the amount of work is excessive.)

For a one-off, [erickson's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953572/how-can-i-get-httpservletrequest-when-in-an-httpsessionlistener/953666#953666) of a [Filter](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html) is really straightforward.

Answer (score 1):

You can't ( see [the API](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html) ). The request allows you to access the session, but not the other way around.

You might even have concurrent requests for the same session, so this is not feasible.

Comment: "You might even have concurrent requests for the same session, so this is not feasible." I don't agree! Only one request will cause the session to be created for which "sessionCreated" is fired. This is an oversight in the spec... for the "sessionCreated" method you should be able to find out which request created the session!