# Redirecting after HttpSession time out

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, timeout

I have been looking at many posts on this topic but couldn't get a solution that works in my case.

I am using Java EE 6 with JSF 2.0 (deployed on JBoss AS 7.1)

In my `web.xml` I have:

```
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>1</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
```

and I **want the user to be redirected to the login page when the session automatically times out.**

what I have tried:

**Approach 1: using filter**

I have tried the following filter:

```
@WebFilter()
public class TimeOutFilter implements Filter {

        @Override
        public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException { 
        }

        @Override
        public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException,
        ServletException {
        System.out.println("filter called");
        final HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
        final HttpSession session = req.getSession(false);
        if (session != null && !session.isNew()) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Has timed out");
            req.getRequestDispatcher("/logon.xthml").forward(request, response);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

In the `web.xml` I have tried

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TimeOutFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

and

```
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>TimeOutFilter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

The filter works as it is called on every request (logging of "fiter called" in the console). **However it is not called when the session times out.**

**Approach 2: HttpSessionLister**

I have tried to use a `HttpSessionListerner`. The method called having the following signature:

```
public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent se) {
}
```

I wasn't able to redirect to a specific page. When I want to redirect a user I usually use the `NavigationHandler` from the `FacesContext` but in this case there is no `FacesContext` (`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` returns `null`).

According to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953572/how-can-i-get-httpservletrequest-when-in-an-httpsessionlistener), the HttpListener cannot redirect the user because it is not part of a request.

**Question**

What is the best way to go to solve this problem? What can I do to make one of the two above-mentioned approaches to work?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4992526/1065197

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Interesting thanks. Although I have never seen the `ViewExpiredException` and I would like, if possible, to redirect to the login page without the user having to click on anything.

Comment: You need some form of polling on your client side to trigger the 302 on your server side. a heartbeat...

Comment: Also related: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543094/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-if-session-time-out-happend-in-jsf-application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543094/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-if-session-time-out-happend-in-jsf-application).

Comment: @BalusC: all these pages would be redirected to the login page, no ? Once there, they would stop polling. If one page performs the logging, another "non logged out" page should use the new session cookie and stay logged in.

Comment: @BGR: what if you've 3 pages open and are active in only 1? 2 pages would after 1 minute be redirected to login page, but 1 not.

Comment: @BalusC These 3 pages should be using the same session cookies (same domain, same path to the heartbeat); thus if page 1 "refreshes" the cookie, 2 and 3 should not timeout

Comment: ok - my bad, if you refresh the cookie - you never timeout (at least using the session timeout mechanism). Won't work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't send a HTTP response as long as the client hasn't send a HTTP request. Simple as that. That's just how HTTP works. The Internet would otherwise have looked very different if any website was able to unaskingly push a HTTP response without the client having requested for it.

A JavaScript based heartbeat based on client's keyboard/mouse activity like as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3201991/auto-log-off-once-the-session-expires/3203250#3203250), or a meta `refresh` header like as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543094/how-to-redirect-to-index-page-if-session-time-out-happend-in-jsf-application/2544766#2544766) would be the solution if you've basically a single-page webapp (thus, you're effectively not using the session scope but the view scope), but that won't work nicely if you've the page open in multiple tabs/windows in the same session.

Websockets is in theory the right solution to push something to the client, but this requires in turn an active session. Chicken-Egg problem. Also, it wouldn't work in older browsers currently still relatively widely in use, so it should currently merely be used for progressive enhancement.

Your best bet is to just define an error page which deals with the case when the enduser invokes an action while the session is expired. See also [javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException: View could not be restored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3642919/javax-faces-application-viewexpiredexception-view-could-not-be-restored/3642969#3642969).

Comment: I now see my misunderstanding. Rather than automatically redirecting the user I need something to let the user know if she performs an action after the session has timed out.

Answer (score 0):

In HttpSessionListerner you cannot send any response to User. One good way to achieve this is with polling, the browser sends HTTP requests at regular intervals and immediately receives a response.
There are many ways to do that:

1. You can use plain old javascript to poll: This will work in cross browser environment.

   function refresh() {

   ```
   // make Ajax call here, inside the callback call:

   setTimeout(refresh, 5000);

   // ...
   ```

   }

   ```
   // initial call, or just call refresh directly
   ```

   setTimeout(refresh, 5000);
2. You can use Web Sockets. Web socket specification is present on below link:

   http://dev.w3.org/html5/websockets/

Answer (score 0):

You could use a Filter and do the following test:

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
if(session != null && !session.isNew()) {
    chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
 else {enter code here
    response.sendRedirect("/login.jsp");
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

I understand that you are using java-EE6 and JSF,but if you could try using JSP code or convert this code below to work in a servlet. Assuming you are using the username to check  for session,after setting the session-timeout in the web.xml file.Please note that JSP code and servlet code are similar.
Your code for validating of session could look like this.(JSP Format)
 If the username serves as the primary key in your database.

```
 <%
    String un = (String)session.getAttribute("un");

    if(un == null){
   response.sendRedirect(login page);
   return;
}else{
      code to process login form
}
    %>
```

Servlet code could look like this

```
String un = (String)session.getAttribute("un");
if(un == null){
   response.sendRedirect(loginPage);
}
```