# How to redirect to a page after session timeout?

Tags: java, session, session-timeout

I have Java web application with two areas: public and private. I have configured session timeouts for both areas. After session timeout I need to redirect to another page.

If the session timeout is from public area, I need to redirect to home page and if the session timeout is from private area, I need to redirect to another page with a message "Your session has timed out !! "
How can I do that ?

Comment: Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15573221/redirecting-after-httpsession-time-out

Answer (score 0):

Well I do not know, what libraries or framework you use, but in general, you can simulate events in Java by using Observer pattern : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern

Your "redirection" logic will be Observer, you register it in session logic, and you notify it, when something happend to session.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you to create HTTP filter for this purpose. This filter is mapped to private zone of your site and does the following:

1. Checks whether session is expired `HttpServletRequest.getSession(false)`
2. if it is expired redirects user to the login page.

Comment: I already have a filter common for public and private zone. Currently in that filter I'm redirecting to a single page on session timeout. How can I differentiate the public and private zone and then redirect to respective pages ?

Comment: I'd suggest you to do this using different URLs. For example put ll public resources under `public` directory and all private under `private` directory.  Then map your filter to private directory only using `filter-mapping` tag  in `web.xml`.

Comment: You can continue with your filter... use the request#getRequestURI () to test whether the URI matches the URI of public or private page and make the appropriate redirects..

Comment: @LucasOliveira, programmatic filtering is good too, but IMHO declarative solution is more modular and allows better code reuse.

Comment: @AlexR In my case I'm not suppose to change the URL because it is already under google tracking. Is there any other way to do this ?

Comment: @KrishnanunniPV, why do you think that I suggest you to change URL? Server side redirect is your friend. The URL in client browser remains the same but the control in server side is redirected to other  page.

Answer (score 0):

`HttpSessionListener#sessionDestroyed()` will be called if you have your `HttpSessionListener` listener configured in your DD.

You can do based on this method call.